# Merging two Data frames in R?

Tags: r, merge

I am new to R and facing this problem (it may be very basic so pardon me). I have looked through the left/right merges and data.table merges but haven't had success.

```
Dataset1: 
Fips     County    Date          Result 
21001    Adair     01-03-2004    0.008 
21175    Morgan    11-21-2002    0.076

Dataset2:
Fips     County    Date          Pre
21001    Adair     01-03-2004    2.08
21001    Adair     01-04-2004    0.076
21001    Adair     01-04-2004    4.76
21017    Bourbon   01-03-2004    0.067
21175    Morgan    11-21-2002    0.076
21175    Morgan    05-04-2004    1.54
21175    Morgan    07-04-2004    0.008
21175    Morgan    11-21-2006    0.076

Desired_output:
Fips     County    Date          Result      Pre
21001    Adair     01-03-2004    0.008       2.08
21175    Morgan    11-21-2002    0.076       0.076
```

This is the code I am using:

```
Desired_output <- merge(Dataset1, Dataset2, by.x=c("Fips", "Date"), by.y=c("Fips", "Date"))
```

But it isn't giving me the desired output. It's just combining everything in the two datasets together?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Check documentation to understand the difference in [inner, full, left and right join](https://r-coder.com/merge-r/).

Comment: I think you just forgot to add "County". You can do like this; Desired_output <- merge(x  = Dataset1, y = Dataset2, by.x = c("Fips", "County", "Date"), by.y = c("Fips", "County", "Date"))

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood the question then this should work:

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(Dataset1, Dataset2, by=c("Fips", "County", "Date"))
```

There is a description of the different types of joins [here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/mutate-joins.html):

Comment: Thank you, I think I have tried this and this gave me a similar result? Like in the desired_output, the number of rows should essentially be the same as Datatset1, no?

Comment: It seems to work for me - it just gives the two rows with the Pre column added on. I've had to re-enter the dataframes so they may be slightly different. Also your Desired_output has different capitalisation of column names to your dataframes ("fips" vs "Fips" and "Date" vs "DATE"). Can you add in the code you use to create the dataframes?

Comment: Hi thanks for pointing that out. I just made a typo in here in the post. I used the correct capitilization.

Comment: The dataframes have been imported from STATA.

Comment: And you are looking to just get those two rows? That is what left_join should do. Check the link that I've added in the answer above.

Comment: Yes. I researched the left/right/inner joins extensively before posting here, thinking maybe I was doing something wrong. Essentially, I should get an output less than my Dataset1 at least. I have about 50k observations in Dataset1 and about 1.2 million observations in Dataset2. The output using left join gives me about 6.2 million observations.

Comment: Mysterious. What data type is the Date field? Can you type str(Dataset1) and post the output here.

Comment: 'data.frame': 49939 obs. of  9 variables:
 ...
 $ DATE         : POSIXct, format: "2004-12-02" "2006-12-07" "2006-08-31" "2005-04-21" ...
 $ RESULT       : num  0.058 0.069 0.031 0.033 0.045 0.038 0.032 0.043 0.045 0.008 ...
 $ UOM          : chr  "MG/L" "MG/L" "MG/L" "MG/L" ...
 $ fips         : num  21001 21001 21001 21001 21001 ...
 $ County: chr  "Adair" "Adair" "Adair" "Adair" ...

Comment: ^ looks smth like this. I deleted some unnecessary variables in the comment

Comment: I've continued to experiment with my made up dataframes and found that when I converted the dates to POSIXct it gave the result you got - it included all rows from my Dataset2. Is it possible to change the date format and try it? That would at least isolate the problem. I used as.Date() to get the column in a different format.

Comment: Thanks for giving this your time, I really appreciate it!
I changed the Date format in both the datasets and then used left_join but the output is identical for some strange reason.

Comment: I'm stumped. Also, as Quniten says, inner_join may be what you're after if you only want rows that are present in both datasets. I had assumed you wanted all from Dataset1 as there were no counterexamples in this data.

Comment: I slept on this and came to the view that it looks like a data type issue because using Quinten's data, which is the same apart from data types, it works. Can you try adding two new columns to each dataframe which are as.character(Dataset1$Date) and as.character(Dataset1$Fips) - and same for Dataset2. That should confirm whether or not it is data types.

Comment: Hey thank you so much for giving this your time, I really appreciate it. 

I tried creating new columns for fips and date (with as.character) and ran the code again, but I got the exact same number of observations as before :(

Comment: No worries, I've enjoyed the challenge and learnt some new things too but have run out of ideas. It really is a mystery why this isn't working though. Not sure if anyone else has any thoughts on why this seems to work with Quinten's dataframes but not with yours. Good luck solving it.

Comment: Nice. I am glad you learnt a thing or two in the process. I learnt a few things too from our interaction. I will just try to build the dataframes from scratch and then see if I have any success using your method and @Quinten's method!

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `inner_join` to get your desired result:

> inner_join(): includes all rows in x and y.

Code:

```r
Dataset1 <- read.table(text ="Fips     County    Date          Result 
21001    Adair     01-03-2004    0.008 
21175    Morgan    11-21-2002    0.076", header = TRUE)

Dataset2 <- read.table(text = "Fips     County    Date          Pre
21001    Adair     01-03-2004    2.08
21001    Adair     01-04-2004    0.076
21001    Adair     01-04-2004    4.76
21017    Bourbon   01-03-2004    0.067
21175    Morgan    11-21-2002    0.076
21175    Morgan    05-04-2004    1.54
21175    Morgan    07-04-2004    0.008
21175    Morgan    11-21-2006    0.076", header = TRUE)

library(dplyr)
inner_join(Dataset1, Dataset2)
#> Joining, by = c("Fips", "County", "Date")
#>    Fips County       Date Result   Pre
#> 1 21001  Adair 01-03-2004  0.008 2.080
#> 2 21175 Morgan 11-21-2002  0.076 0.076
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>